# proof of $A\cap(B \triangle C)=(A\cap B)\triangle (A\cap C)$ using DeMorgan's laws

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I could prove this by using Venn Diagrams, but I couldn't use DeMorgan's laws to prove it.
I also used this method:

x
        ∈
        A
        ∩
        (
        B
        △
        C
        )
      
    
    
      
        ⇒
        x
        ∈
        A
         
        a
        n
        d
         
        x
        ∈
        (
        B
        △
        C
        )
      
    
    
      
        ⇒
        x
        ∈
        A
         
        a
        n
        d
         
        x
        ∈
        (
        B
        ∪
        C
        )
        −
        (
        B
        ∩
        C
        )
      
    
    
      
        
          
            
              ⇒
              x
              ∈
              (
              A
              ∩
              (
              B
              ∪
              C
              )
              )
              −
              (
              A
              ∩
              B
              ∩
              C
              )
            
            
              =
              (
              (
              A
              ∩
              B
              )
              ∪
              (
              A
              ∩
              C
              )
              )
              −
              (
              (
              A
              ∩
              B
              )
              ∩
              (
              A
              ∩
              C
              )
              )
            
          
          
            
            
              =
              (
              A
              ∩
              B
              )
              △
              (
              A
              ∩
              C
              )

How can I prove it by using DeMorgan's laws?
Any hints would be appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: What is the meaning of the triangle-symbol ?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 mathjax reference.

Comment: △means symmetric difference

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{align*}
(A\cap B)\triangle (A\cap C)
&= ((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C))\setminus((A\cap B)\cap(A\cap C)) \\
&= (A\cap(B\cup C)) \setminus (A\cap B\cap C) \\
&= (A\cap(B\cup C)) \cap (A\cap B\cap C)^c \\
&\stackrel{\cdot}{=} (A\cap(B\cup C)) \cap(A^c\cup B^c\cup C^c) \\
&= (A\cap(B\cup C)\cap A^c)\cup(A\cap(B\cup C)\cap B^c)\cup(A\cap (B\cup C)\cap C^c) \\
&= (A\cap(B\cup C)\cap B^c)\cup(A\cap (B\cup C)\cap C^c) \\
&= A\cap(B\cup C)\cap(B^c\cup C^c) \\
&\stackrel{\cdot}{=} A\cap(B\cup C)\cap(B \cap C)^c \\
&= A\cap ((B\cup C)\setminus (B\cap C)) \\
&= A\cap (B\triangle C).
\end{align*}

The equalities with dots over them are applications of De Morgan's laws. It is much easier to read, and not much more difficult to follow, if we skip several steps:

\begin{align*}
(A\cap B)\triangle (A\cap C)
&= ((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C))\setminus((A\cap B)\cap(A\cap C)) \\
&= (A\cap(B\cup C)) \setminus (A\cap B\cap C) \\
&= A\cap ((B\cup C)\setminus (B\cap C)) \\
&= A\cap (B\triangle C).
\end{align*}
The third equality here hides much of what we did before, which includes the steps explicitly using De Morgan's laws.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
From the second step to the third step, does it mean A\B = A∩Bc?

Comment: @user3741679 Yes, $A\setminus B = \{x; x\in A \land x\notin B\} =A \cap B^c$

Comment: Yes. $A \cap B^C$ means everything in A but not B, and common notation for that is $A \setminus B$.